# Linux server encrypting and decrypting files on demand

Tags: linux, encryption, document-management

I have a DMS (Document Management System) running on a linux server and want to have the files encrypted when the DMS saves them on disk. I also want to decrypt them when the user click to download them.

Any thoughts on how I can reach this configuring the server?

Answer (score 2):

Set up full disk encryption, and have the document management system store files within the file system that lives within the encrypted container.

No, seriously. It's a simple solution that appears to meet your needs perfectly:

- Files are encrypted while at rest (stored on disk in encrypted form)
- Files are automatically encrypted and decrypted on an as-needed basis
- The document management system does not need to know anything about the encryption

You might want some way to open the encrypted container (which is a once-per-boot operation most of the time) without having someone actually enter a passphrase. If you aren't willing to shell out the money for a proper [hardware security module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), there are software solutions which, while they won't get you all the way there, can certainly make it harder for an adversary to gain access to the passphrase. (I'm aware of at least one piece of software for that, but can't seem to recall what it was called nor find it. If I can think of it later, I might add a link.)

On Linux, this means setting up a dm-crypt or LUKS container which in turn holds a file system. Mount that file system somewhere, and tell the document management system to put all documents within that mount point directory.

Comment: What if I encrypt my disk and after that I pay for more space on the server. How to proceed?

Comment: @EduardoAlberice You can resize a LUKS container, if that's what you are asking. After that, you can resize the file system within it. How to do it would be a different question, or two.